# how would i make a range of two dates bold or highlighted on a monthcalendar on vb?

Tags: vb.net, date, range, monthcalendar

I'm using VB and SQL and so far I managed to do

```
    Dim start_date As Date = DateTimePicker4.Text
    Dim end_date As Date = DateTimePicker3.Text
    MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange = New SelectionRange(start_date, end_date)
    MonthCalendar1.BoldedDates =
```

and this is where I am stuck, thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: start with Option Strict On (cannot convert string to date)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calander in MySQL is not linked to the injection that you had created. It can lead to a security vulnerability.

As for the highlighting part, try using an OpenSQL query subform.

Comment: Kindly add some more content